# Can i use my Razer naga hex on ubuntu?

Tags: mouse

I am thinking to use Ubuntu, i only have one mouse, Razer naga hex. Im just asking if i can use my mouse, And i configure my mouse on Ubuntu, It only says "Compatible with Windows and mac" On the side of my box.

Answer (score 1):

The mouse likely *works* as a mouse (there are plenty of people out there on the internet posting about using it in things) but the software used to configure it won't.

For my Razer Mamba I installed the configuration application in Windows in VirtualBox and used VB's USB passthrough feature. This was a bit clunky but it worked for simple configuration.

Now I've no idea how the Naga Hex presents its little thumb-pad... It could just be throwing out extra mouse buttons (make the most sense) or it could be acting as a software-driven keyboard. I'd personally be optimistic about making it work the way you wanted to, but that might only come after a battle.

---

This [Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145502) suggests it presents as a mouse and a keyboard (groan) so you'll likely need some form of Windows around to keep it configured. I say that because I assume the configuration software tells it what keyboard combinations to send out.

Ultimately you're going to need to try it before you know if it gives you what you want.
Give it a go in a LiveCD and see.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Im using the roccat pure + and that works fine and you can even edit the profile on it. So it works ok just need to learn the command and shortcut